# UITableView cell separator line thicker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have attached an image of cells in a table view, and you can notice the 2 separator lines in the middle are a tiny bit thicker/darker than the 2 outer lines. I want the lines to all be consistent, and the color/thickness of the outer two lines. I could not find a solution, so I am wondering if anyone knows of any. I figure it would be a simple solution, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Thanks guys.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Select your `UITableView` from xib or storyboard, then make the `UITableView` separator to `None`.

See the image

[image]

Then place a `UILabel` with the width same as of `UITableViewCell` and height=1 in the bottom of your cell, clear the text of the label and set the `backGround` color as per your wish, this will solve your problem.

Comment: This gets rid of the lines. I want to keep them, but just make the middle two thinner/the same color as the outer two lines.

Comment: Edited the answer, check.

Comment: Have a look to this simple code that allows you to create your custom separator for each cell https://github.com/PabloAlejandro/PALinedCell

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps you.

Create a custom separator Line Programatically:

```
UIView *separatorLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
                CGRectMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 1.0,   
                cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 1)];
separatorLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];;
[cell.contentView addSubview: separatorLine];
```

or you can add a image view for separator in custom UITableviewCell in UI